# Is there a way to specify a fixed (or variable) number of elements for lxml in Python

Tags: python, html, lxml, screen-scraping

There must be an easier way to do this.  I need some text from a large number of html documents.  In my tests the most reliable way to find it is to look for specific word in the text_content of the div elements.  If I want to inspect a specific element above the one that has my text I have been enumerating my list of div elements and using the index of the one that has my text to then specify a previous one by acting on the index.  But I am sure there must be a better way.  I can't seem to figure that out.

If not clear

```
for pair in enumerate(list_of_elements):
    if 'the string' in pair[1].text_content():
        thelocation=pair[0]

the_other_text=list_of_elements[thelocation-9].text_content()
```

or

```
theitem.getprevious().getprevious().getprevious().getprevious().getprevious().getprevious().getprevious().getprevious().getprevious().text_content()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/xpathxslt.html#xpath) supports [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/):

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring("...your xml...")

el, = root.xpath("//div[text() = 'the string']/preceding-sibling::*[9]")
```

Comment: But I am a beginner how does this do me any better - and I am using html.  I started with mytree=fromstring(thedocument) and then list_of_elements=mytree.cssselect('div')

Comment: @PyNEwbie: The above xpath expression is just an example, it should be something like `elements[-1].xpath("preceding-sibling::div[9]")` in your case.

Comment: I've added combined xpath expression

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick?

```
from itertools import islice
ancestor = islice(theitem.iterancestors(), 4) # To get the fourth ancestor
```

**EDIT** I'm an idiot, that doesn't do the trick.  You'll need to wrap it up in a helper function like so:

```
def nthparent(element, n):
    parent = islice(element.iterancestors(), n, n+1)
    return parent[0] if parent else None

ancestor = nthparent(theitem, 4) # to get the 4th parent
```

Comment: I am playing with ancestor right now trying to figure out how to manipulate the objects in it.  I see that I get four ancestors.  Thanks

Comment: @PyNEwebie see my edited answer.  The code I gave you initially didn't do what you needed it to do.

Comment: Thanks I understand more and this is helpful.

Comment: `islice` returns an iterator therefore you should write `next(isclice(..), None)` instead of `parent[0] ..`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), and then provide an index?